# How do I do paginating in Nokogiri when the number of pages is not readily available?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, nokogiri

I'm trying to learn how to build a custom screen-scraper that downloads to a local directory, and I'm following "The Great Bastards Guide" by Danny Ngyuen. I have a question that was not addressed in the book: What if the page I am trying to scrape doesn't have the last page number visible in their pagination scheme?

Several sites limit the number of pages that are shown in their results until you get near the end, like Google. How would I define `last_page_number` when it isn't visible on the main index. Alternatively, is there a better method to take Nokogiri through the pagination when all I have is a next page link?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'fileutils'
BASE_URL = 'http://explore.data.gov'
BASE_DIR = '/catalog/raw/?&limit=100&page='
LOCAL_DIR = 'data-hold/datagov-pages'

FileUtils.makedirs(LOCAL_DIR) unless File.exists?LOCAL_DIR

# get metainfo from first page:
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(BASE_URL+BASE_DIR + '1'))

# write the HTML for page 1 to disk
File.open("#{LOCAL_DIR}/1.html", 'w'){|f| f.write(page.to_html)}

last_page_number = page.css("a.end.lastLink.button")[0]['href'].match(/page=(\d+)/)[1].to_i

puts "Iterating from 2 to #{last_page_number}"

for pg_number in 2..last_page_number do
  puts "Getting #{pg_number}"
  File.open("#{LOCAL_DIR}/#{pg_number}.html", 'w') do |f| 
    f.write( open("#{BASE_URL}#{BASE_DIR}#{pg_number}").read )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number of pages isn't a known value, like it is on the site in your example, then you have decide whether you're going to try to read an indefinite number of page, or limit your search to *n* pages.

Google might actually be able to return a thousand pages, or more, of a particular search, but the value of pages after the fifth is very questionable. So, for Google limit your scrape to the first *n* pages.

For a site where all pages are interesting, and it doesn't have a known ending page, then you'll have to manually navigate to the last page, and pick out something that is your code "landmark", then search each page you retrieve, so you know when you've arrived at it.

Or, you can start at page 1, and keep incrementing until your code fails to get a page. To do that, you have to wrap your "Get a page" code in an exception handler, so that when it fails your code doesn't blow up, and you can exit gracefully.

Comment: In my theoretical example the landmark would be the absence of the next page button. I was thinking that I would include the css selector for the next page and then while loop until it is no longer visible. Is this a good way to go about this and if so how would you change the above code to loop properly but still maintain the scraping and disk writing processes.

Comment: Yes, that tactic would work. How to implement it is for you to figure out. It isn't hard.

Answer (score 0):

usually when you try to reach unexisting page you'll get an 404 HTTP status. You can increment the page number until you get an 404 error.